# How to define a message contract in WCF?

Tags: wcf

I've read that it is possible to define your own message contract in WCF, to give yourself complete control over the SOAP message. When would this be necessary, and how is it accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Microsoft programming guide documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx) gives a good overview.